# UIView animation for CGAffineTransformMake not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a simple transform animation that moves a UITableViewCell 70 pixels to the left. In the  `if` part, the animation works just fine and I get a smooth transition. However, when the function is called again to put the cell back in its original position, which is the `else` part, I get no animation. It just returns back to normal but without animation. How can I fix this?

```
 if([[slideArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]==0)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        selectedCell.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-70, 0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [slideArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];

    }

    else
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        selectedCell.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [slideArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
    }
```

Comment: Not sure it will help your problem at all, but the normal way to specify your second transform is CGAffineTransformIdentity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try the following animation in else condition  this will work fine if you alreadyb have perform translation of if condition....

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
    selectedCell.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(70, 0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [slideArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
```

if above code not working for you than try the following

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                  delay:0
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
             animations:(void (^)(void)) ^{
                 myImageView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-70, 0);
             }
             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 myImageView.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;
             }];
  [slideArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
```

let me know if any  issues ..
regards.

Comment: Setting the transform back to `CGAffineTransformIdentity` after the animation fixed it for me. Thanks!